# Easy pole placement over long distances

Tags: factorio

Whenever I want to place poles over long distances and try to maximize their wire distance to save poles, it is difficult to do so.

Is there anyway which allows you to hold down LMB and only place poles whenever the pole's wire reached their maximum distance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's exactly how the power poles work. Place one, hold down LMB, and move. Once you reach maximum distance, you'll automatically place another one.

One warning: the logic screws up when you get to somewhere that already has poles. So there, you'll have to manually place another pole to finish the connection.

Comment: I tested it out a few times. Seems like sometimes it does occur, but otherwise it just spams the poles like other objects. Is there anyway to make it happen all the time?

Comment: @WenQin Do you know under what circumstances it spams vs works correctly?

Comment: @WenQin It might not work if your cursor has moved too far forward (or backward) relative to your character so that the next spot to build a power pole is not in build range. You should hear the "cannot build" sfx if that happens.

Comment: Are you holding down the mouse and moving your character around, or are you holding down the mouse and moving the mouse? The first is what you want to do, the second will cause pole-spam.

Comment: I am moving my character as I hold the LMB. There is no circumstances, it just happens really randomly to me.

Comment: @WenQin: Going by that description, this almost sounds like a hardware failure more than a game mechanic failure. This first thing that breaks on a mouse is often the "springy" bit that enables clicking, and when that wears out, the mouse starts registering double (or more) clicks every time you click the mouse as it starts making false contacts.